# Google Chrome Developer tools - Cannot set breakpoint

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

What have I done?
I'm running a ASP.net / Polymer website in VS2010 Development server.

It all used to run fine I could set a breakpoint in some JavaScript, run the site in Debug mode and it would break at the set location.

I obviously changed something though because now I can only set a breakpoint once the Javascript is loaded or by putting a *debugger;* statement in the code

Actually, I can set a breakpoint (or appear to) but it doesn't break at that location

Answer (score 2):

Just me being stupid again
It turns out the problem was because I had added the folder containing the Javascript source to the workspace (by right clicking in the **Sources** pane)

Having done this the folder tree which used to appear under the **localhost:nnnnn** parent in the Sources pane no longer showed

Don't remember adding them but obviously I did
Removing the folders fixed it

I mainly put this answer here so that the next time I do the same thing and look it up on Stack Exchange I will find the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best way to add a breakpoint with Chrome is just adding this in the code:

```
debugger;
```

So long as the code is actually run and you have the javascript console open it will be caught.

But sometimes the I have found the dev tools get broken and require the entire browser to be restarted.